# Is there an equivalent in PHP to .NET's datasets?

Tags: php

ASP.NET has the concept of a dataset to capture the data and build relationships with the data, and maintain good performance without having persistent SQL connections.

Is there something similar in PHP that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about php active record? It's an open source ORM library available for php. http://www.phpactiverecord.org/

Comment: Thanks i will have a look that